# AS3 Flash, AIR3+, Android share intent with navigateToUrl

Tags: flash, android-intent, air, navigatetourl

I created my first android app using Flash CS5.5/AIR 3. Im trying to figure out how to create and call an intent to share an image via whatever apps the users device supports. This article explains how to create the intent http://androidthings.blogspot.com/2011/10/adding-share-button-to-your-android.html#.UJ6fD4fAd8E

... but I believe it is in reference to using eclipse/java/android sdk.

From what I understand passing an intent through a navigateToUrl is now possible in AIR3+ with the example code here http://forums.adobe.com/message/3873002

Im new to android development using Flash/air and trying to put the pieces of all this together. Although there are a few posts about this... none of them truly clarify how to implement a share intent this way. Anyone know how to pull this off?